# python: receive big data from socket

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

how I can receive large data from socket with loop?
The size of the data can changed during the program so it must be loop.

I heard I can do something like this

```
 while socket.recv(1024)
     data = data + socket.recv(1024)
```

but in this way I am pretty sure i this way some data will lost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry answer was supposed to be a comment. Apologies.

Most networking protocols use headers to advise the recipient of the size of incoming data (You could use a separate message).

For instance, (i will assume the machine running your script as the 'server', and the machine providing the information as the 'client')

Client code could first measure the size of the data you need to send `len(data)` and send a message to server advising of the data length. This message can be parsed for size, then this number can be passed to `socket.recv()`

Can post code later, i am currently AFK :)

Comment: but may the data will be bigger than 1024

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, i have edited the answer again however, i am sorry the response has been rather broken

Comment: and what i am doing with the len ? put him like this socket.recv(len)?

Comment: Absolutely :) that process will allow for dynamic allocation of sock.recv()